# Creating .NET/.NET Core/.NET Standard C# Class Library on the fly for testing purpose

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, class-library

I'm developing a tool that updates some C# (Class Library) projects' properties programmatically. 
At the moment unit tests are based on projects that already exist in a solution path, but, for several reasons (e.g. not having unnecessary objects and files) I was wondering whether it's possible to create projects and access their properties at tool's execution time.

Some doubts:

1. I'm aware that there's a Project type in Microsoft.Build.Evaluation but that belongs to .NET 4.8 only. Is there some sort of equivalent in .NET Core/Standard?
   [image]
2. When I create a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project is there a way to get/set all the properties that define the project and are visible in Visual Studio Properties View?
   Is it possible to do it without saving the project in a directory?

I'm using Buildalyzer to simplify project's properties access but it requires a path where a project already exists.

```
var analyzerManager = new AnalyzeManager();
var project = analyzerManager.GetProject(@"C:\ClassLibraryToTest\ClassLibraryToTest.csproj");
AnalyzerResults results = project.Build();
var fooProperty = results.Results.FirstOrDefault().GetProperty("FooProperty");
```

Therefore, I have to use a project that already exists in my filesystem, or I could create a project on the fly but still I should save it on filesystem like this:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project();
p.Save(@"C:\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.csproj")
```

3. I know that with dotnet CLI we can use the following command to generate new class libraries:

   dotnet new classlib -n FooClassLibrary -f targetFramework

But is it possible to access to those underlying methods and properties, without using CLI?

4. Might dynamic be helpful in my case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for what's in the System.CodeDom namespace? This allows you to generate .NET assemblies on-the-fly from another .NET program.